# Thread.sleep() not working. Operations being skipped

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop, sleep

This code is supposed to search the html file of a webpage, print some results to a window, sleep for 60 seconds then search again repeatedly. This worked in python just fine but translating to java is giving me problems. When I try to execute this code, it no longer prints the results but just sleeps indefinitely. Without the while loop, things seem to work as aspected.

```
btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            running = true;

            while (running) {

                exportField.setText("Searching...");


                try {

                    exportField.setText(crawler.fetchHtml(url););



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    exportField.setText("invalid parameters.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        }
    });
```

weirder still, if i try something as simple as:

```
exportField.setText("Searching...");

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {              
    e.printStackTrace();
}

exportField.setText("Done Searching");
```

I would expect the output to be "searching..." *pause* "done Searching" but this is not the case. it just outputs "done searching."

Working on this project for fun! Any help would be much much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me like you are inside of the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). If that were the case, your `sleep()`s would operate just fine - the repaints on your `exportField` are just never (in case of while) or delayed (in case of simple sleep) happening.

You should consider looking into [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for this long-running but UI-changing sort of calls.

A simplified approach would just start a thread and update UI via [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)):

```
btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            new Thread("Fetcher") {

                boolean running = true;

                public void run() {
                    running = true;

                    while (running) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> exportField.setText("Searching..."));
                        try {
                            exportField.setText(crawler.fetchHtml(url));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> exportField.setText("invalid parameters."));
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(60000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();              
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @Jan. This seems to be a step in the right direction! I don't know anything about threading but this code and these links should help a ton.

Comment: Once you're satisfied with an answer, it'd be great if you accepted it. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3):

You are starting an infinite loop inside an actionPerformed method as far as I can tell (assuming the running isn't set to false somewhere), this will block all events on the event dispatch thread. Have a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for swing. Long running events like @Jan said should be done with a SwingWorker or on a separate thread at least

Comment: Thank you for the link @dbrown93 Got somewhere to start on this bug at least!